# How to set Custom Operator parameters by custom logic

Tags: python, operator

In my addon dialog interface, I customize the content using the overridden draw function.

I would like to have buttons in that interface, that sets the parameters by some custom logic. For example these buttons:

1. Set the parameters to their default values (as specified in class definition, eg. FloatProperty(default=1.0))
2. reads values from a json files, process it, and set the parameter values from it.
3. checks all blender scene object locations, calculates the mean, sets the values based on it.

I have only found one solution that I am happy with (for option 1). It is by using the built-in operator "wm.operator_defaults".

in my draw function, it might look something like

```
box = layout.box()
c = box.column(align = True)
r = c.row()
r.operator("wm.operator_defaults")
```

to get functionality for points 2 and 3, i have created a secondary operator. It looks like this horrid thing:

```
class ResetROperator(bpy.types.Operator):
  """Small operator class to reset the parameters for a R operator"""
  bl_idname = "mesh.reset_r_operator"
  bl_label = "Reset R object to defaults"

  def execute(self, context):
      op = context.active_operator
      if op.name != 'Add R Object':
          raise RuntimeError("must be called from R operator only.")
    
      # PERFORM LOGIC, E.G. READING FILES OR ANALYZE SCENE CONTENT

      op.VARIABLE_NAME = RESULT_OF_ANALYSIS
      return {'FINISHED'}
```

I then call this operator from within my draw, just as with the "wm.operator_defaults" example, but explicitly as "mesh.reset_r_operator".

This puts important logic of my operator outside of the operator, and opens for errors. It is just not a nice solution from a SW engineering perspective, and I am hoping for a better solution from the community. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. This would be done in an operator [invoke](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#invoke-function) or using custom properties stored on the scene for example for better serialization.

Comment: invoke is only called once, correct? So how can it be used to implement the three buttons? Custom properties on the scene (as opposed to in a json file).... I dont understand how I can get to a solution.

Comment: A diagram mockup would help a bit, I have trouble visualizing what you want to achieve